# RxJava filter and react to events?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to test a QR code with a specific format in an `Android` application using `RxJava`. I need to check the QR code for several conditions and if are true, I would need to stop further checking and react to them, e.g. show an error message in the UI that the QR code is not valid.

I read that using `Observable.error` is not recommended as it should only be used for extreme events, but the events I'm filtering are not extreme, but can be expected, e.g. the QR code that was scanned was not created for my application or the data contained in the QR code is invalid. Otherwise I would have thought about something like this:

```
Observable.just(barcode)
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Barcode>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Barcode barcode) {
                        if(barcode.rawValue == null) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("empty");
                        }
                        if(barcode.rawValue == null) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("empty");
                        }
                    }
                })
                .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends Barcode>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<? extends Barcode> call(Throwable throwable) {
                        //do something here
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Barcode>() {
                   //update UI to show result
                });
```

What would be a good practice to test my barcode for data without sending the stream to `onError()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a separate type to describe the `Barcode` scanning result. i.e.

```
class BarcodeScanningResult {
    Barcode barcode;
    String error;
    public BarcodeScanningResult(Barcode barcode, String error) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
Observable.just(barcode)
    .map(new Func1<Barcode, BarcodeScanningResult>() {
        @Override
        public BarcodeScanningResult call(Barcode barcode) {
            if(barcode.rawValue == null) {
                return new BarcodeScanningResult(barcode, "empty")
            }
            if(barcode.rawValue.trim().length == 0) {
                return new BarcodeScanningResult(barcode, "blank");
            }
            return new BarcodeScanningResult(barcode)
        }
    }).subscribe(new Subscriber<BarcodeScanningResult>() {

})
```